# Overwrite files during startup

Tags: startup

I am trying to overwrite a file whenever my computer is logged in after a restart or log-out then log-in.

- Location of the file: `/user_data/somePrefs.txt`
- Location of file to    be replace :
  `/software_location/somePrefs.txt`

I can certainly try to do a manual copy-paste method so as to overwrite the file but it can be a hassle to do so whenever my computer is rebooted/ logs out.

Is there an automated way to do so during startup?

Comment: Your desiring three things `startup(boot), reboot`, and `logout-login` which is it as `boot` and reboot` are quite different things AFAIK?

Comment: you can put the command with exec in your ~/.bashrc eg. `exec command`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click, new Document, Empty Document. *(create it anywhere you like)*. Name it anything ending with `.sh` (example: StartupCommands.sh)
2. Type `#!/bin/bash` in the first line
3. (the tricky bit) Type your copy command in the next line. It should look exactly like the line below. Don't forget `'` the quotations

   ```
   cp '/path/to/user_data/somePrefs.txt' '/path/to/software_location/somePrefs.txt'
   ```

and the path has to be an "absolute path" (starting from root and all the way down to your files).

...so finally the file should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp '/path/to/user_data/somePrefs.txt' '/path/to/software_location/somePrefs.txt'
```

4. Right-click your `.sh` file, Properties, under Permissions, check the box "Allow executing file as program"
5. open "Startup Applications" *(press the start button and search for it)*
6. click "Add"
7. You can type what you want in the "Name" and the "Comment" fields
8. click "Browse..." and select your `.sh` file

done. cheers.

*If you need help with step 3 tell me in a comment*

---

## Hint for step 3

*You can open a new terminal. Drag and drop the `somePrefs.txt` files (one at a time) into the terminal. What appears in the terminal is the absolute path.*

Answer (score 0):

Now this is the command that needs to achieve what you want:

```
cat /user_data/somePrefs.txt > /software_location/somePrefs.txt
```

Now we have three scenarious:

1. Startup, a.k.a. boot:

   - in this case we can use the `systemd` program to achieve this at every boot

     1. Create a script in any location with the above command.
     2. Make permission `755` with: chmod 755 name_of_file
     3. Create a `systemd` service file like thus:

        ```
        [Unit]
        Description=copy script

        [Service]
        Type=simple
        ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/path/to/file/copy.sh"

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target
        ```
     4. Call it what you may, here I will call it `cop.service`
     5. Place that file in the `/etc/systemd/system/`
     6. Enable it with:

        - `sudo systemctl enable cop`
     7. It will run that file at every boot
2. At reboot:

   - Use `cron` to run it.

     1. Set it up like so:

        ```
        crontab -e
        @reboot /path/to/cop.sh
        ```
     2. And at every reboot that should run
3. At logout-login:

   - Place that command file in the `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file and it will be run at every logout and login
   - Make file executable with: `chmod +x /path/to/cop.sh`
   - Add: `/path/to/cop.sh` file
   - Source file to make sure no error: `source ~/.bashrc`
   - Now any time you log out and in tha script runs.

Simple sample script with your command would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /user_data/somePrefs.txt > /software_location/somePrefs.txt
```

**NOTE:**

You would need to change the directory paths as per your own situation.